# Problema no me guarda la imagen en la base de datos

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el problema que al querrer subir una foto para luego mostrarla esta no se guarda en la base de datos y en ves de guardarse toma el valor de "vacio"

las metodos que ocupo son estos

```
class comentarios{

    static function agregar($comentario, $CodUsua, $CodPost,$imagen2)
    {
        $con = conexion("root", "");
        $consulta = $con->prepare("insert into comentarios(comentario, CodUsua, CodPost,Imagen) values(:comentario, :CodUsua, :CodPost,:Imagen) ");
        $consulta->execute(array(
                    ':comentario' => $comentario,
                    ':CodUsua' => $CodUsua,
                    ':CodPost' => $CodPost,
                    ':Imagen' => $imagen2
                    ));
    }


    static function mostrar($CodPost)
    {
        $con = conexion("root", "");
        $consulta = $con->prepare("select U.nombre, C.comentario,C.imagen from usuario U inner join comentarios C on U.CodUsua = C.CodUsua where C.CodPost = :CodPost");
        $consulta->execute(array(':CodPost' => $CodPost));
        $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
        return $resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, indica como tienes definida la tabla comentarios, para ver que tipo de campo es Imagen. Te informo tambien que no es buena practica guardar la imagen en uno de los campos de tabla. En su lugar, es mejor guardar la imagen en un directorio reconocido y en el campo la ruta y el nombre del archivo.

Comment: ¿Tienes idea de cual es el valor de `$_FILES` en la línea 53 de `inicio.php`? igual puedes hacer un `var_dump($_FILES)`  para ver en pantalla con que estás lidiando. Cuando hay error en el proceso, el nombre de los archivos puede quedar en blanco.

Comment: estoy guardando la ruta en la base de datos y el tipo dr dato es var char ... la carprta donde guando la.imagen lo puse en la variable $destin